# Save Entire Twitter Timeline Including Recommendations from People I follow

Tags: twitter, rss

### Question

**Is it possible to save entire timeline with recommendations into RSS Feed?**

The information in the example below with red markings on it,  is what I am after.
Since from what I have found so far, I am only able to retrieve information from my timeline, without twitters recommendations. ( my own tweets, retweets, or likes) I want to archive everything if at all possible.

**Alternatives that I have thought of, if this is not possible.**

Individually, capture all information of each user that I follow ( their tweets, retweets, and likes)
It would be tedious, but it would be one way.

I do know that their are rate limits.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Sources that I have tried without success

[Converts Twitter to RSS Feed](https://rss.app/rss-feed/create-twitter-rss-feed)

[twarc is a command line tool and Python library for archiving Twitter JSON data](https://github.com/DocNow/twarc)

[Twitter timeline](https://github.com/rmotr-group-projects/pyp-w4-gw-twitter-timeline)

### Example of My Timeline

[image: Twitter Timeline Save Recommendation]
[image: Twitter Timeline Save Recommendation]

Comment: This looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225364/getting-whole-user-timeline-of-a-twitter-user. Unfortunately that's a software development question with Python script as answer, not Web App one.

Comment: I will take a note in depth look at this later. Maybe this question was put in the wrong place. Thanks

Comment: @HQJaTu Unfortunately, that just grabs all the users personal tweets, likes and retweets, but not the information related to their timeline ( information recommended by twitter)

Comment: Ok. As the solution is code, it should be possible, even relatively easily, to alter the code to do what you need.

Comment: @HQJaTu It would be easy if I was after the information you wrote about. Unfortunately, I am not sure Twitter lets you get the data I am after. I am going to make another post on stackoverflow about it. I am so pissed that the mods would not move it over to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found this website [here](https://www.allmytweets.net/connect/), which basically downloads the entire twitter feed of another person. Where then you can download it or turn it to pdf, or even control+a, control+c, and put into the document.

It's not your normal feed, but if you do this for the people you follow the most then you will get similar results if the reason for doing this is reading tweets offline.

I also found another website [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-save-your-twitter-timeline-to-a-file-with-a-simple-script/), which is basically a script that downloads your entire twitter timeline.

Here is the script they wrote for it:

```
   1  #! /bin/bash
   2
   3  PASSWD=my_Twitter_password
   4  USER=mfioretti_it
   5  COOKIEFILE=/tmp/cookiesShtw.txt
   6  COOKIE_LINE="--cookie $COOKIEFILE --cookie-jar $COOKIEFILE --user-agent Mozilla/4.0"
   7  # twitter_dump.html is a temporary file, useful for debug purposes
   8  rm -f  /tmp/twitter_dump.html
   9  # log in to Twitter
  10  curl -s $COOKIE_LINE --data "username=$USER" --data "password=$PASSWORD" --data 'commit=Sign In' https://mobile.twitter.com/session > /dev/null
  11
  12  #see timeline
  13
  14  curl -s $COOKIE_LINE http://mobile.twitter.com > /tmp/twitter_dump.html
  15
  16    egrep '^<strong|^<span class="status">'  /tmp/twitter_dump.html    | \
  17    sed 's/href="\//href="http:\/\/twitter.com\//g'     | \
  18    sed 's/ class="twitter-atreply"//g'                 | \
  19    sed 's/ class="twitter_external_link"//g'           | \
  20    sed 's/ class="twitter-hashtag"//g'                 | \
  21    sed 's/ rel="nofollow"//g'                          | \
  22    sed 's/^<strong>//g'                                | \
  23    sed 's/<\/span>$/<br>/g'                            | \
  24    sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/<\/strong>\n<span class="status">/ : /g;p;}'
  25  exit
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately that website just does your own tweets. It doesn't provide the ones that are generated by your timeline.

Comment: Have you personally tried that script because it was written in 2011?

Comment: I tried them both for my own tweets and they both worked. I didn't try them for others, but they said they could. Sorry for not double-checking :/ I'll delete the post in around 30 minutes to make sure you see the comment. Again sorry for not double-checking, thought it would help.

Comment: No, don't . I appreciate it. Seriously. I've done my homework though and it's really important to me .That's the only reason why I'm commenting on yours.

Comment: Alright, thanks for understanding :) I'll do so more research and edit my answer if I find anything new.